# Wordpress / HTML code: Pictures don't get displayed properly on mobile view

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I've got an online shop, based on wordpress, with the theme "Mystile".

I created many pages with own HTML and CSS codes and they're looking very good on the computer, in every browser and display size. But the automatic mobile view of the theme is displaying all the self coded stuff terribly.

For example: I'd wanted to display some pictures side by side, so I used a HTML code like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 250px;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 500px;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
```

The pictures get displayed side by side on every desktop device but unfortunately not proberly on the mobile view.

On other themes mobile view you can defenitely notice a defined width of the view, so my pictures get displayed in a way that they fit in the mobile view. In my current theme this is not the case, it seems that the mobile view is just a kind of convertion of the whole website and not a clearly defined box where the content gets displayed.

I really stuck here because the website is finished coded and it looks very good on the computer, on any display size ect. Only the mobile view is the problem.

What can and should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: You can create an alternate CSS file for the mobile layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The Mystile theme is a responsive theme and has a so called "viewport" meta to make sure the presented size is optimal to the device:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The positioning you're using for your images does not respond to the device width, because you're using absolute positioning (in your case: the first image is left: 0px, the second one is left: 250px, third is left: 500px).

Overall, absolute positioning is considered bad practice (if your attempting something responsive), a solution I would suggest is to make the images `inline-block` and shrink them if they don't fit anymore. In that way you have what you want on large screens and everything shrinks if the screen get's smaller.

```css
.wrap {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.singleimage {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 33.3%;
}
.scaleimage {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="singleimage"><a href="myhref"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" class="scaleimage" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="singleimage"><a href="myhref"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" class="scaleimage" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="singleimage"><a href="myhref"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" class="scaleimage" alt="" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help but this didn't worked for me. First of all I had to change the percentage because it didn't looked good on the computer. And when I now scale down my browser the pictures overlap each other.

Comment: You're right, the absolute positioning is making life hard ;) Personally I would look into making the `<div>` elements `display: inline-block;`. Then you don't have to worry about the margin-left hack you're applying.

Comment: I tried it with "display: inline-block;" can't notice any changes. Does unfortunately not work.

Comment: To dive into this more, this is probably what your current situation does:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctb83h36/, and I'm guessing this is a solution which would work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ctb83h36/3/. It's all about properly using/defining which elements do what.

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate how to reach a solution.